# Unable to hide sideNavBox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css

I have a requirement where the complete side navigation should be hidden for normal users.

I have the below in my masterpage

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">        
     <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#sideNavBox').show();
        });
    //]]></script>        
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

..
..
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList" style="display:none!important">
```

However the sideNavBox remains in display for normal users.
The css is below:

[image]

Why am I not able to hide the `sideNavBox`?

Even `$('#sideNavBox').hide();` does not have an effect, whereas `$('#contentBox').hide();` hides the content in the page

**UPDATE:**
`display:block` was mentioned in a CEWP in my homepage, and was causing issues; once it was removed, I was able to hide and show the sideNavBox using `$('#sideNavBox').attr('style', 'display: block !important');`

Comment: Why you have added `$('#sideNavBox').show();` in document.ready() if you want to hide the sideNavBox?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, the sideNavBox is normally hidden. The javscript is supposed to run only for some users as defined by SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like SPSecurityTrimmedControl.

I had situations in the past where it wouldn't work as advertised.

That said, you might be having a case of "important" keywords being assigned.

If sideNavBox has an important style, hide() might not work.

Give this a try:

to hide

```
$('#sideNavBox').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
```

to show

```
$('#sideNavBox').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
```

Comment: well, this worked.

However, I need to initially hide it on page load, and then show it only for admins.
Wondering how to do that.

Comment: you know how to hide and how to show. you can do one through the inline style and the other as you do on document ready, just use display block instead of show, that should work

Comment: the problem is that inline style of `display:none!important` is not having any effect now. It's getting overriden as shown in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: it seems that you might be overdoing it. based on the screenshot, I would say, remove any inline styles. then set a single display none entry, in your master.css (without important) and then do a simple .show() in the master page. if there is a particular reason for the need of important, just use attr instead of show. so, default/hidden/css and admin/visible/script. you don't need both inline and css doing the same thing. hope this helps

Comment: `show()` didn't work for me even when `!important` was absent. I was able to display the `sideNavBox` using the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint uses its own body onload function called *_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames* which will collide with your document ready (run before or after).  If you are loading your JavaScript files through the elements.xml file (through a feature in Visual Studio), this can be particularly problematic with the order of how things load.

Instead, create a function with a custom name, and push the custom name into the *_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames* array.  It’s wonderful and allows things to load in their proper order.

Have you tried this?

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("showSideNav");
function showSideNav() {
     $('#sideNavBox').show();
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, I am not able to hide the sideNav with `$('#sideNavBox').hide()` even after the page has loaded. If it is not displayed, I can check if a conflict is happening.

Comment: Hit "$('#sideNavBox')" in console and see if you get the element. If not then you do not have it in your DOM.